# css/html: вывод элементов, занимающих высоту не больше заданной

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

подскажите, можно ли с помощью css/html без привлечения js реализовать следующее:

есть блоки `div` одинаковой высоты, но разной ширины (в зависимости от содержащегося в них текста) - по сути это "строковые теги", типа `[мама] [папа] [братишка] [сестренка]`

когда тегов много, то они могут занимать несколько строк, типа

```
[мама] [папа] [братишка]
[сестренка] [бабушка]
[дедушка] [жучка] [внучка]
```

можно ли ограничить вывод тегов некоторой максимальной шириной, так чтобы МАКСИМУМ выводилось 2 строки (если тегов хватает только на 1 строку - выводится 1 строка тегов)

P.S.

более сложный вопрос - если это возможно, то можно ли это как-то засекать (пусть и с использованием js), чтобы в таком случае выводить дополнительный тег/развертку

```
[мама] [папа] [братишка]
[сестренка] [бабушка] [...]
```

P.P.S.

конечно все это можно реализовать через подсчет длины слов внутри тегов и т.д., т.е. с использованием JS, но встал вопрос - можно ли это как-то сделать без оного

Comment: max-height, не?

Comment: да, такой вариант работает, недостаток - отсекает остальные ряды и никак это не увидеть, а хотелось бы конечно дополнительно добавить элемент, показывающий, что произошла "свёртка" элементов

Comment: @Zhihar может еще добавить text-overflow (добавляет троеточие в конец обрезанного текста)

Comment: @АлександрСычёв, но это работает только, если строка одна.

Answer (score 0):

CSS стили...

overflow: visible; ---> Отображается все содержимое элемента, даже за пределами установленной высоты и ширины.

overflow: hidden; ---> Отображается только область внутри элемента, остальное будет скрыто.

overflow:scroll; ---> Всегда добавляются полосы прокрутки.

overflow: auto; ---> Полосы прокрутки при необходимости.